# Trying to get string between 2 delimiters

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a bit of an issue by trying to get a string between 2 delimiters using linux commands.

I am trying to retrieve `TEST|LOL` from `"AA CC [[TEST|LOL]] EE FF"` using sed.

I've used this command,but it gives me an error, 
    `invalid reference \1 on 1 s commands RHS`

Command that i am using at the moment:

```
echo "AA CC [[TEST|LOL]] EE FF" | sed 's/.*[[\(.*\)]].*/\1/g'
```

So is there any possibility of fixing that command?Or maybe creating a bash script without the use of an IFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the `[` and `]` as well

```
$ echo "AA CC [[TEST|LOL]] EE FF" | sed 's/.*\[\[\(.*\)\]\].*/\1/g'
TEST|LOL
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of grep supports it, you can use the Perl regular expression mode:

```
echo "AA CC [[TEST|LOL]] EE FF" | grep -Po '\[\[\K[^\]]*'
```

The `-o` switch means that only the part of the input that matches the pattern is printed. The `\K` removes the first part of the pattern from the output.